# What would the name Rod be an abbreviation or shortening of?

Tags: nicknames

Can anyone come up with more names than Rodney, Roderick or something quite different for "Rod"? I'm trying to track a Rod Anderson down and cannot find either of those or just Rod.

Answer (score 0):

Tried googling "boys names rod"?

Found this site with a few: http://www.babynamespedia.com/start/m/rod

It claims the most popular Rod- names are Rodney, Roderick, Rodrigo and Rodolf.

Comment: 'Rod' might also be short for 'Nimrod'.

Comment: What about Rodolfo?